# Beginner Node.js pass json as callback for function

Tags: node.js, httprequest

Apologies as I'm a bit of a beginner, but am trying to put the get request in variable within a function so that I can call it in another function and have it return the JSON.

```
function getRequest (url, response) {
var response = request.get({
            url: url,
            json: true,
            headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
          }, (err, res, data) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log('Error:', err);
            } else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
              console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
            } else {
              console.log(data);
            }
    });
}
```

Then I have 
`var result = getRequest(urlPlaylist);`
and have it return the JSON from the function.  Can someone help me figure out how to structure that callback?  Thank you!

Comment: See the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) to the question that yours has been marked a duplicate of.  It covers all the various options for returning an asynchronously retrieved value.  A variant of this question is asked multiple times a day here since it's one of those things all people who are new to network programming in Javascript have to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request is async, so you can't just return it. Try something like this, where you pass a callback to be called when the json (data) is ready.

```
function getRequest (url, cb) {
  request.get({
    url: url,
    json: true,
    headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
  }, (err, res, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error:', err);
    } else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
      console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
    } else {
      cb(data);
    }
  });
}

getRequest(urlPlaylist, function (json) {
  console.log(json);
});
```